# Testing @PostConstruct with Mockito (Junit5)

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5, postconstruct

I'm looking for ways to test a private method with a @PostConstruct over it. How can I achieve this?

I tried looking for answers but so far got only a few which describe using @RunWith. As it is not available in Junit5, I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: Mockito's purpose is to mock things. Your problem, if i understand correctly, is to test a `private` method. 1. So simplest solution would be to increase visibility to `package private` (`default`)  and then you will be able to call it (and unit test it) from the test class (because test class should have the same package). 2. Alternatively you could instantiate the bean and check that whatever was supposed to happen in `@PostConstruct` indeed has happened.  3. Lastly (but I don't recommend this) you could invoke the private method with reflection.

Comment: Hi @JAsgarov, thanks for your detailed reply. I've used the reflection way to go about testing it. I'm kinda aware it is not a recommended way because we are going against the purpose of declaring the method private in the first place. Could you tell if there are any other reasons why you wouldn't recommend using reflections?

Comment: For test purposes it is not tragic, but in general code written with reflection can easily break or have unintended effects, either because of something simple like change in method signature which would not be caught at compile time because reflection looses the static typing OR due to some changes in future JDK versions (they often introduce additional security measures to reflection). Other disadvantages include increased coupling, less readabilitiy, etc. Therefore, if you have a better alternative (like previously mentioned option 2 for example) you should prefer that.